# What do the red lines in Chrome's timeline mean?

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, profiling

I'm trying to identify the cause of a long frame. The timeline shows a red line extending beyond a scroll update, but does not indicate what this means:

[image: Screen capture of Chrome timeline, including unexplained red line]

Where do I find more details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It represents time spent waiting for the main thread.
[image]